# Javascript google map api function that i need help understanding

Tags: javascript, html

I do mostly back-end work and know very little javascript (emphasis on the word little). I came across some javascript code embedded within the html page of a website. Now i am not sure what's happening here.

What i understand is, it's a javascript google map api function of some sort(maybe i am wrong). What i need to understand is what it's doing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api    
    /js?key=*********************&libraries=places">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtPlaces'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {                                                                                                
            var place = places.getPlace();
            var address = place.formatted_address;
            var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
            var mesg = "Address: " + address;
           /* mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
            mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
            alert(mesg);*/
    document.getElementById('locc').value =   address;
        document.getElementById('latttt').value = latitude;
       document.getElementById('lonnnn').value = longitude;
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="loc" id="locc" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="latitu" id="latttt" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="longitu" id="lonnnn" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

It's then setting the value of three input boxes based on data from the google maps.

(Also, on a side note I'd hide the personal api key in the script tag just in case)

Comment: Places autocomplete? So, it's not a map api?

Comment: It's a function you can use as part of the Maps API

Comment: If this has been helpful to you, please accept/up vote this answer :)